# In Lua, does indexing a table with a table as the key call the __eq metamethod?

Tags: lua, metadata

I am wondering if `table[key]` where `key` is a table with a metatable will call the `__eq` metamethod. For instance, if the table has a key `"a"` and the __eq metamethod returns true if "a" is being compared to the metatable, will indexing the table with the table return the value for "a"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, indexing uses raw equality: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4

You should consider explicitly converting your objects to their string representation before indexing instead of relying on implicit metamethods.